# Kafka consumer is stuck on ReadMessage when Close() is called

Tags: go, apache-kafka, concurrency, goroutine, confluent-platform

I have a worker in which there are 3 goroutine consuming using `consumer.ReadMessage(-1)`, and when I call `consumer.Close()`, some of these goroutine (2) are stuck at `consumer.ReadMessage(-1)`. 

It seems that before `Close`, some of these goroutine called `ReadMessage` but was stuck as `Close` was also called.

 Any Idea how to resolve this ?

Edit: I am using confluent-kafka-go

Comment: Please mention the package used as it's not always possible to guess them by looking at method calls.

Comment: Please provide a sample reproducible code so people can help you better. use can use https://play.golang.org/.

Comment: @shmsr Added `confluent-kafka-go`

Comment: Why you're indefinitely waiting `ReadMessage(-1)`? I think you should provide a small snippet of your code where you're using these methods (or reproducible example code)

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too — despite its „harsh“ title.

Comment: Hello! Have you solved it? I have the exact same problem. The process just does not let go. I do not want to use time limits